# Get port name in SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-dpi

I wonder if the modules have any visibility into the hierarchy of the ports? Can the port hierarchy be printed out?

For a minimum working example, assume I have this:

```
module top ();
  
  logic my_sig;

  child ichild (.sig(my_sig));

endmodule : top


module child (input logic sig);
  
  initial $display(/* SystemVerilog-Fu here */)

endmodule : child
```

I expect the `$display` to print `top.my_sig` -- or something that conveys `my_sig` name instead of just reading out the value. I looked into the DPI guide as well, but it doesn't seem to have any such facility.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I did try `%m` -- that only conveys the module name. I needed the signal name instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DPI is for behavioral modeling interoperability between SystemVerilog and C. The VPI gives you the introspection you are looking for in from C. Also, many tools have a command line interface (`find signals -ports` in Modelsim/Questa without having to learn a complicated C API.

Explaining how to do this is too deep a discussion for [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/). I suggest you read my DVCon 2016 paper on [SystemVerilog introspection](https://verificationacademy.com/resources/technical-papers/introspection-into-systemverilog-without-turning-it-inside-out) with examples [here](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/DQDG).